# Spring Boot: Using Tomcat context parameters in logback configuration

Tags: spring-boot, logback, tomcat8

I have several instances of a Spring Boot app deployed in a unique Tomcat.
Each app is configured with a context.xml file which contains a customer code

```
<Context path="/myApp1" reloadable="false">
    <Parameter name="CUSTOMER_CODE" value="CUSTOMER1" />
</Context>
```

I wish that each customer has a separate log based on code defined in context.xml.

Unfortunately this config doesn't work in my logback-config.xml:

```
<property name="LOG_FILE" value="${ROOT_LOG}/${CUSTOMER_CODE}/myApp.log}"/>
```

A folder CUSTOMER_CODE_IS_UNDEFINED is created in "ROOT_LOG" directory. "ROOT_LOG" is provided by a system property.

Is there any way to make this logback configuration working?

The use of properties defined in application.properties works well (I renamed my logback.xml to logback-spring.xml). It seems to me that Spring boot does not set Tomcat context parameters in Environnement before initialize logging. Any idea for a workaround? Thanks.

Comment: I think the custom logback config (logback-spring.xml) will do what you need: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#boot-features-custom-log-configuration - mainly you probably just need to rename your config file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried with logback-spring.xml but it didn't work. I updated the post to add more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution to get my customer code available in Spring Environment bean before logging initialization. Not very pretty but it's working:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

  public static String APP_CUSTOMER_CODE;

  /**
   * Initialization of Spring Boot App with context param customer code
   */
  @Override
  protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(final SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
    final Map<String, Object> initProps = new HashMap<>();
    initProps.put("CUSTOMER_CODE", APP_CUSTOMER_CODE);
    return builder.properties(initProps).sources(Application.class);
  }

  /**
   * Method called before Spring Initialization
   */
  @Override
  public void onStartup(final ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    APP_CUSTOMER_CODE = servletContext.getInitParameter("CUSTOMER_CODE");
    super.onStartup(servletContext);
  }

}
```

In addidtion, i must declare a **springProperty** tag in logback-spring.xml to use the variable:

```
 <springProperty name="CUSTOMER_CODE" source="CUSTOMER_CODE"/>
```